# What does the parenthesis mean when used in a typescript type in a key?

Tags: typescript

Can anyone please give an example object that fits the following typescript type? Kind of puzzled since I only used interfaces before and only saw squared brackets before.

```
type Hash = {
  (data: Uint8Array): Uint8Array
  blockLen: number
  outputLen: number
  create: any
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures).  In this case, it means that a `Hash`, in addition to having `blockLen`, `outputLen`, and `create` properties, is also *callable* like a function that takes a parameter of type `Uint8Array` and returns a value of type `Uint8Array`:

```
const hash: Hash = function (x) { return x };
hash.blockLen = 1;
hash.outputLen = 2;
hash.create = "who knows";

const hashed = hash(new Uint8Array([1,2,3]));
// const hashed: Uint8Array
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwBZQLxQN4FgBQV9QAUAJnMHAFxQCqAlgHbAAcAggE5twgCUVdjrDl1wEoAIwA2AewDGAawAyEelXoBXALZiIbEQSlrgYQ0pVR1WnXvwy2EMhCpx6IXAF9cuGVPoJgUJEQkKnhkNCgAMzV6GWBaHyIAD25MKDtgNTZ6KESoNwBuXEDkADpJWUVlcIBGQpxipBKDIxMq9AAmOoaS23tgaHQAIgB3JCkoOXopYYRBuqKgsul5UxLgKQAxWkSIYkJ27nmcb19-Bt3whsJ6CGGaBmZ2ThBCAG1qgBoodq+AZgBdbiHXAAehBUBOfgCQV2fAegmeQA)